# Export from JSON always return "Blob is not defined"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, next.js, fs

I want to create an excel file from my database, after that the file will be saved in the stored/client/ folder.

I use `export-from-json`

```
import exportFromJSON from "export-from-json";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import { Blob } from "buffer";

import db from "./dbConnect";
import Client from "../models/Clients";

function isRealValue(obj) {
  return obj && obj !== "null" && obj !== "undefined";
}

async function exportData(client, time) {

  const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), `stored/client/${client}`);
  
  await db.dbConnect();

  const result = await Client.findOne({ client: client }).lean();
  await db.dbDisconnect();
  const exportType = exportFromJSON.types.xls;

  if (isRealValue(result)) {
    fs.writeFile(
      postsDirectory,
      exportFromJSON({ data: result.message, fileName: client, exportType }),
      function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Results Received");
      }
    );
  }
}

const dataFn = { exportData };
export default dataFn;
```

but the result always "Blob is not defined". I have tried to change into [simple data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-from-json) like `export-from-json` did and the result still the same.

[image]

Comment: `blob` and `Blob` are different things, it's important to report errors accurately.

Comment: [`Blob`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#class-blob) was only added to Node.js in v15.7.0 (ESR) / v14.18.0 (non-ESR). What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: i using nodejs 16.13.2

Comment: I'd include that in the question.

Comment: @HeruWijayanto You have to pass a `processor` function like in the `export-from-json` Node.js example.

Comment: so this function can't be run without giving params request? @juliomalves